# How to create one batch file to scan all code languages supported by fortify?

Tags: fortify

Currently, I am scanning java code in a repository using fortify batch file and scanning C/C++ code in the same repository using the command line with the help of visual studio integration.

Is it possible to scan both java and C/C++ code in a repository using a single batch file? 
Also, is there command line options to scan both coding languages at once?

Comment: Please post your code you have tried with the problems or errors you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you probably shouldn't.

One scan (one FPR file) should represent one codebase. Unless you have one application that's part Java and part C/C++, you want to produce 2 separate FPRs, one for Java and one for C/C++.

Instead, take your 2 scan scripts, write another very short script that calls them, and voila, a script that scans both your applications.

If you do have one application with both languages, here's what you do:

Fortify first translates your source code into its intermediate language (NST files), then it scans those NST files. The translation is the sourceanalyzer command where you point it to your code, and the scan step is the sourceanalyzer command with -scan in it. It uses the build ID to keep track of those intermediate files (that's the argument after -b).

To scan the whole codebase together, first translate one set of files, then translate the other set of files (using the same exact build ID), and then do the scan step (same build ID), and it'll scan all of the code together. But only do this if it really is one application.)